# Como faço pra retonar quantidade de registros Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jpa

Quero retornar o valor de registros de `playlists` no banco, mas esse código ai não funcionou.

```
public interface PlaylistDao extends JpaRepository<Playlist, Long> {

    @Query("select count(*) from Playlist")
    public int verifica();
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class PlaylistServiceImpl implements PlaylistService {

    @Autowired
    private PlaylistDao dao;

    public int verifica(){
        return dao.verifica();
    }
}
```

Comment: tenta alterar de "int" para "Long" no retorno do seu método.

Comment: @AdrianoGomes Como isso ajudaria? Um `int` vai até **`2.147.483.647`**, certo?

Comment: Henrique, por favor, especifique o que você quer dizer com "este código não funcionou". Ele não compila? Retorna erro? Retorna zero? Retorna um número nada a ver com o esperado?

Comment: @LINQ o retorno do count no hibernate é um Long e não um inteiro, por isso acredito que o Spring jpa se comporte da mesma forma.

Comment: @AdrianoGomes Agora faz sentido =D

Comment: Troquei pra Long, e testei:public static void main(String[] args) {
        PlaylistServiceImpl se=new PlaylistServiceImpl();
        System.out.println(se.verifica());
    }

Comment: Da um java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Seu teste está errado. Você não pode usar `new PlaylistServiceImpl()`, deste modo as injeções de dependências não são feitas. Leia esse artigo para você entender melhor: [Injeção de dependências com Spring](https://blog.algaworks.com/injecao-de-dependencias-com-spring/)

Comment: Experimente  `@Query("select count(p) from Playlist p")` e avise se funcionar.

Comment: Deu NullPointerException , tenho que saber o tipo de retorno que coloco

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Essa resposta é [a mesma da outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/345516/qual-tipo-de-retorno-de-um-select-count-no-spring-jpa) *semelhante* criada pelo mesmo contribuidor. Porém, como não foi marcada como duplicada ainda, respondi aqui também. Estou sugerindo como duplicada agora.</sub>

A interface `JpaRepository` (que herda de `CrudRepository`) já vem com um [método pronto](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#count--) para essa ação.
Ele se chama `count()` e retorna um `long`.

Ao invés de declarar um método novo, você pode usar esse.

Veja a [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts) para mais informações.