# Qual tipo de retorno de um select count(*) no Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, spring-data, spring-jpa

Preciso saber o tipo de retorno que o Spring JPA retorna pra colocar no pacote Service, pois está dando um `NullPointerException`:

Dao:

```
public interface PlaylistDao extends JpaRepository<Playlist, Long> {
    @Query("select count(*) from Playlist")
    public int verifica();
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PlaylistServiceImpl implements PlaylistService {

    @Autowired
    private PlaylistDao dao;

    public int verifica(){
        return dao.verifica();
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual o erro completo? Em que ponto dá NullPointerException?

Answer (score 2):

A interface `JpaRepository` (que herda de `CrudRepository`) já vem com um [método pronto](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#count--) para essa ação.
Ele se chama `count()` e retorna um `long`.

Ao invés de declarar um método novo, você pode usar esse.

Veja a [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts) para mais informações.

Answer (score 1):

Ele retorna um Long, devido a sua natureza de count.

```
TypedQuery<Long>
```

Comment: Testei com int, Integer, long, Long e sempre da NullPointerException

Comment: A consulta retorna algo? Digo, se já testou ele mesmo na base de dados sem o java

Comment: na base de dados a query é diferente, é query SQL ("select count(*) from playlists") , retorna uma coluna count(*) com a quantidade de registros

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e coloque a _stacktrace_ da _exception_ que você está recebendo. Aproveite e apague a outra questão que você abriu referente a esse código.

Comment: Tenta pegar a consulta SQL referente ao seu JPA, e teste essa mesma consulta diretamente na base de dados para verificar se a mesma retorna algo

Comment: O Fato de retornar NULL, muito provavelmente não está relacionado com o tipo de dados do retorno.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a notação do Spring JPA Repository para fazer o `count`, conforme igventurelli disse:

```
public interface PlaylistDao extends JpaRepository<Playlist, Long> {

    long count();

}
```

Se quiser contar por algum atributo da entidade, basta acrescentar o

```
long countByName();
```

Se deseja fazer um `count` mais complexo, que envolva o `@Query`, você pode fazer:

```
@Query("SELECT count(*) FROM Playlist")
long countPlaylist();
```

Se deseja usar o *Entity Manager* com o seguinte Jpql:

```
String jpql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Playlist");
```

Você pode usar o `TypedQuery<Long`>:

```
TypedQuery<Long> query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql , Long.class);
long total = query.getSingleResult();
```

Ou `Number`:

```
Query queryCount = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
long total = ((Number) queryCount.getSingleResult()).longValue();
```

Para ler o resultado final.

Answer (score 0):

Boas praticas de usar um jpql e colocar um alias

```
@Query("select count(p) from Playlist")
public Long getSizeOfPlaylist();
```

porém estranho o count do CrudRepository não esta funcionando pois é nativo do spring

```
public int verifica(){
    return dao.verifica();
}
```

já que esse trecho acima e bem redundante, bem eu diria que todo esse código para pegar apenas a quantidade não tem necessidade, você fazer isso com 1 linha;

```
dao.findAll().size();
```